# How to submit information to a Feed and viewable Profile ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Right now I have a UI that allows users to load files from their computer to a list of the files, an input that puts a photo in the area, and text field for the title, date, and description.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
class RBD extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      files: [],
    };

  }

handleClick = event => {

  // Helper code to read file and return promise
  const readFile = (file) => {

    // const fileList = [];

    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    // create the promise and return it
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      // if file reader has an error, report it
      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject({ error })
      }

      // if success, resolve the promise
      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        resolve({
          name: file.name.replace( /_|\.mp3/gi, " "),
          link: e.target.result

        })
      }

      // start reading the file
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    })
  }


  // create all the file reader promises
  // create an array from the files list and use map to generate
  // an array of promises
  const allReaders = Array.from(event.target.files).map(readFile)

  // Now handle the array of promises we just created
  Promise.all(allReaders)
    .then(fileList => {
      console.log(fileList)
      // set the state that we have all the files
      this.setState({ files: fileList });
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.error(error)
    });

}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="downloadMusic">
        <div className="input">
          <input
            accept="audio/*"
            onChange={this.handleClick}
            id="upload-file"
            className="inputName"
            type="file"
            multiple
            ref={this.inputRef}
          />
          </div>
          <div>{this.state.files.length > 0 && <Downloaded/>}</div>
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
          <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
              <div
                {...provided.droppableProps}
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
              >
                {this.state.files.map((file, index) => (
                  <Draggable key={file.name} draggableId={file.name} index={index}>
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                      <div
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}


                        style={getItemStyle(
                          snapshot.isDragging,
                          provided.draggableProps.style
                        )}
                      >
                      <div className="handle">
                      <Handle {...provided.dragHandleProps}/>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                         <form>
  <label>
   <p> &nbsp;<input type="text" defaultValue={file.name} name="name" style={{width:'600px', height:'30px', fontSize: '16px'}} /></p>
  </label>
</form>

                      </div>  
                      <div className="delete">
                       <LIDelete onClick = {() => this.removeItem(index)}/>
                       </div>
                     </div>

                    )}
                  </Draggable>

                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </div>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default RBD;
```

```
const Downloaded = (props) => {

 return(

        <div className="main-content">

            <div className="container">
                <div className="downloaded">
                <div className="image"><ImageUpload/></div>
                <form className="downloaded-form" action="/action_page.php">
                <label>
                   Title:&nbsp;
                     <input className="title" type="text" name="downloaded-name" placeholder="Title"/> 
                     </label>
                     <br/>
                   <br/>
                   <label>
                   Release Date:&nbsp;
                     <input type="date" name="date" />
                   </label>

                 <br/>
                 <br/>

                     <textarea rows="12" cols="50" placeholder="Add Description"/>

                        </form>
                    </div>






            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Downloaded;
```

```
class ImageUpload extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { file: null };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
    });
  }

  resetFile(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ file: null });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <label>
       Choose Cover:&nbsp;
        <input type="file"  accept="image/*" onChange={this.onChange} />
        </label>

        <div className="image" style={{ width: '300px', height: '300px', 
            border: '1px dotted black', position: 'absolute'}}>
        {this.state.file && (
        <img style={{ width: "300px", height: "300px"}} src={this.state.file} />
        )}
        </div>

        {this.state.file && (
          <div>
            <button style={{marginTop: '300px'}} onClick={this.resetFile}>Remove File</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageUpload;
```

So my question is how do I take this information and store it on a feed with the photo, title, and description and also in the users profile with all the above and also the list into a playlist (I think I know how to write the playlist I just need to know how to transfer the information. I'm guessing by using props but how?).

Comment: > how do I take this information and store it on a feed

do you want to store the information in a database, localstorage? what do you mean on a `feed`?

Comment: @ncubia a live feed how you can see information or posts (photos, the date added, description, etc) from yourself and the people who added new posts.

Comment: @ncubia I think I'm using MySQL and NodeJS?